What is the most advanced engine for deep space use that could be developed between around 1970 and 1990 with an IPP level space budget?
There have been a lot of different concepts that were studied for propulsion, but most of them are still quite far off engineering wise and even the closer ones are limited by budget.
"IPP level budget" in this situation means budgets comparable to what was wanted by NASA for the Integrated Program Plan, although a bit raised towards the later end. For the purpose of the question, this means space budgets around 0.6% to 0.4% of US GDP roughly ever year, and a HEU NERVA solid core Nuclear Thermal Rocket entering use around 1978.
The question is, what is the most advanced engine they could develop for deep space use by around 1990?
Assume that initial work on the project begins shortly after 1970, but that larger scale efforts only begin around 1980 after NERVA enters use, with a goal of entering service around 1988-1990. It can be an engine type that was only thought up later but would be feasible with the technology of the period mentioned.
(Note: Orion is not an option, smaller scale orion derived designs maybe but not just plain orion)
Edit: For reference for what IPP level budgets means for the rest of the space program see this document, the September 1969 Space Task Group Report to the US president:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710002945/downloads/19710002945.pdf
The schedule being used for this is the Maximum Rate Program. Although IRL the highest level seriously endorsed was the Option 1 program which would've taken a bit longer. As to why exactly almost none of what was mentioned happen the short answer is "they didn't want to pay for it", the long answer is easily multiple books worth of information (and there are several books about it).

While it could be said that theoretically had there not be the imposed timelines of the space race superimposed on the cold war that a more advanced engine could have been developed... but I think that's wrong. Technology is a pyramid with the apex knowledge depending on the knowledge, experience, successes, and failures that came before it. In other words, it wouldn't matter how much money you threw at it, I doubt in Real Life that a significantly more advanced engine could have been developed without the experience those engines provided in the first place.

BTW, we host "what are the limits of Real Life?" Qs from time to time. I'm not convinced they're worldbuilding, but they do fall into the [tag:alternate-history] paradigm. They also rarely bear significant fruit because of that knowledge pyramid problem. Money helps do things faster, sure, but you still need to build facilities, run tests, fail from time to time, etc., and all that takes time. Usually the time you're trying to avoid by throwing more money at it. I hate to say it, but as a modern-day example of the problem, look at the effort to adopt electric vehicles. Money ain't enough.

@JBH the problem with applying this idea to space travel is that what is possible with regards to technology and what is possible with regards to money have practically never aligned since FY 1968. Like seriously, when you read any overarching history of space travel, there is a persistent pattern of engineers and scientists saying "We can do this in X years with Y budget" and the response being "We simply don't want to if that's how much we'd have to spend.

I can't explain it very well but read the Space Shuttle Decision and Humans to Mars: Fifty Years of Mission Planning, 1950-2000 (both free online) and the False Steps and No Shortage of Dreams blogs. It comes down to the issue that irl they simply were not building the facilities and running the tests.  What is technologically possible and monetarily possible haven't aligned since congress looked at NASA plans in 1967 for the Apollo Applications Program and said "We don't want to pay to build more than 15 Saturn Vs, so your not going to do this because it needs more than 15 Saturn Vs."

Money isn't enough but when governments have consistently just said "We're not giving you anything to work towards this goal because we think it's too expensive" for more than 75 years. EV adoption isn't at all a comparable situation because governments haven't just said "Too expensive, we're not doing it" to the goal of EV adoption. The idea of the pyramid problem is not at all applicable to Space Travel because fundamentally there has been an extremely low level of effort placed into it. Because politicians were presented with what was technologically possible and simply said "No".

I'm sorry, OT, but a lifetime of experience.... Engineers are notoriously bad at estimating how long they can do anything and how much money it would take. (That's comming from an engineer....) As long as you don't mind a [tag:science-fiction] grade answer, don't listen to me.

"Adavanced" is not actually a measurable metric, are you talking about? Do you want the highest thrust the best specific impulse, max Delta-V, is throttling an issue, what about maneuverability, longevity, fuel efficiency, etc...? Also you need to be editing some (most?) of the information in those marathon comments into the body of the question.

@JBH Has every space engineer of the last 50 years genuinely been decades off their predicted timelines for if they were given money to actually develop anything?

@Ash primarily just thrust and specific impulse, i'll add it to the question. most of the comments isn't really relevant to the question it's more just me being annoyed by people not understanding space history

At the level you're talking about, yes. As an example of the problem, when I was designing circuits back in the 90s, we knew from experimentation and mathmatics, that it was impossible to build a 1nm FET transistor. Everything we did was based on that belief. And that belief held until 2016 when the 1nm FET was invented. Engines are more than engines. They're fuel and materials science and electronics and programming and you bet, there isn't a legitimate "yes" answer. Just cool SciFi maybes.

@jbh wait i'm confused now. Isn't the current latest process node 3nm which was created in 2022? IIRC 2nm is meant to become a thing this year or next year and 1nm is supposed to be created in 2027. And looking at the document you posted a lot of the discrepancies can be traced back to successive governments simply cutting back funding to programs. Like for example Space Station Freedom was a political mess.

"One-Nanometer Transistor Keeps Moore’s Law Relevant Another Year" There's always a difference between cutting-edge tech and common process. The 1nm breakthrough was in 2016 and you have a 3nm common process today because of it. Back when I was designing chips. Common-process was 100nm with no hope of shrinking it down (hence the title of the article).

One more anecdote. I don't know how old you are, but I'm 57. I'm old enough to have seen science be proven wrong and replaced with a better understanding. It's more than "I grew up with rotary telephones" (although it's unlikely most users on WB.SE understand what that means...). I've seen it happen enough to know that whatever science humanity understands today is nothing more than a stepping-stone to what it'll understand tomorrow... and some of it will be proven wrong and replaced by new knowledge. Science isn't the end. It's literally the process of stepping away from the beginning.

Definitely nuclear fission propulsion, the NERVA program was wildly successful and essentially had the technology ready for space flight but was cancelled before they actually use it.
If the tech had continued to be developed further we could have had some of the most efficient and powerful rocket engines possible with current tech. Only really being surpassed by nuclear fusion engines in the distant future.
Mars certainly would have been doable much earlier, I'm not sure if their would be incentive to go further than Mars but if there was then a nuclear fission engine probably could have accomplished it.
One can only imagine what a Saturn V with nuclear propulsion could have accomplished. With enough funding an inter planetary transport network could have been possible with a docking/refueling station around the moon and mars for nuclear powered shuttles to go between in a reasonable time frame. A permanent manned mars base could have been possible.
However this all assumes the funding is actually available but I could absolutely see at minimum a trip to mars being possible.

"Nuclear fission propulsion" is a vast concept space - we're nowhere near having the tech for a gas-core NTR or dusty plasma engine even today. Could you specify which fission designs you think are plausible with additional funding in the 70s-90s? (I wouldn't expect much more than NERVA, and that has a lot of disadvantages.)

Well, or Timberwind or something, maybe. In either case, solid-core seems like the only thing that even engineers with 2020s experience might have any idea how to do.

@parasoup NERVA is Nuclear fission propulsion, the designs that came from that project worked and were efficient. I'd be skeptical if it couldn't have been improved further with more time and funding.

Sure. (The biggest problems are that a solid-core NTR is hard to reuse and quite heavy for its efficiency, cutting into fuel mass savings especially once cryogenic storage for H2 is added.) There are many, many other nuclear-fission rocket designs; my point is that you don't specify which ones might've been possible. Some fission designs are absurdly beyond even our current knowledge.

NERVA: Technically feasible, practically questionable.
There is plenty of information on what was the plan for NERVA and the proposed NERVA II (NERVA development start around 1953 for the theory, 1968 for first tests).
See Wikipedia on NERVA, source 72 [PDF], 73 [Book: Dewar, James (2007). To The End of the Solar System: The Story of the Nuclear Rocket (2nd ed.). Burlington, Ontario: Apogee. ISBN 978-1-894959-68-1. OCLC 1061809723] and Project Rover)
It is said in the article, that at first it was aimed at a 20,000MW (20GW) nuclear rocket engine. But plans for feasible missions in the time between 1975-1990 made clear that a 5GW engine would be sufficient already (dubbed NERVA II). The main purpose was for inter-planetary maneuvers and a lunar shuttle (this nuclear shuttle was also part of W. von Brauns plans of reaching the Mars soon after Apollo; not to be confused with the Space Shuttle program that was realized later).
There were test engines built that proofed the concept of a nuclear rocket engine (NERVA XE about 1.1GW). However, there were concerns back then already what would happen if a single-use rocket with a nuclear engine would re-enter atmosphere, crash into the ocean and maybe sink to depth of 3km worth of pressure in salt water [Wikipedia/NERVA]. Meaning: Pressure could be high enough to crush the reactor, salt water would act as a moderator to get the fission going and marine life would suffer. Explosions in the atmosphere would even be more severe. The plans were to have a very low failure rate (3 in 1000 starts) - but you never know. In 1973 the project was cancelled anyways.
Keep in mind the world-wide shock 1986 with the Chernobyl disaster. Opposition towards a nuclear powered space craft, performing multiple starts per year, would surely have hardened ever since.
If all those concerns were not applicable for one reason or another, to facilitate development of nuclear rocket engines, the best we could have by 1990 would be a nuclear driven space shuttle which also could reach the moon. So maybe first stages of a moon base would be possible also. And with a moon base mars comes closer into reach (as mentioned, the NERVA (II) upper stage on an advanced Saturn V was deemed necessary to reach mars back in the days).
Moon/Mars is not exactly deep space, but back then, the plans were not so much aimed at deep space. Mission proposals were aimed at lower earth orbits and satellite deployments, which could be done with conventional rocket engines well enough, maybe even cheaper. Most famous programs being the Hubble space telescope and the International Space Station (ISS).
There is not much to go to beyond mars for manned missions either. Exploring deep(er) space was done recently with probes mainly, so the need for nuclear driven rockets is not given that much in this field.
If the envelope really has to be pushed for nuclear propulsion there would have had to be a reason "what to achieve" with it. Otherwise the focus would not be at this one operation like in the time with Apollo but spread broader/thinner among several projects and missions. An upper bound could be the 20GW mark envisioned for NERVA at the beginning.

I probably should've included this in the question and i'll add it now but by IPP level budgets i mean the budgets required for the maximum rate 1969 Integrate Program Plan presented by the director of NASA  to the US President in 1969. Mars landings and a 48 man moon base were meant to happen around 1981 enabled by the Nuclear Shuttle (a distinct vehicle from the Space Shuttle, Space Shuttle was for Earth to low earth orbit, Nuclear Shuttle for everything beyond that)  more details at: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710002945/downloads/19710002945.pdf

True, I did not really crunch numbers on budgets really. I think this would be too much of a speculation. I focused more on what could be possible because there were plans back in the days already, what they wanted to do next. I just assumed all those plans would be realizable given "enough" money. No matter how much "enough" is.

Integrated your hint about the Space Shuttle program, but i do distinguish between nuclear and "normal" shuttle in the answer (only the nuclear shuttle is mentioned tho). @OT-64SKOT

"First stages of a moon base" seems rather optimistic; given the timeline and development path of e.g. Mars rovers, I suspect it'd be more accurate to say "first stages of the long and grueling process of discovering everything we didn't know we needed to start a moon base".

@Antares mrem, makes sense

@Cadence early lunar bases were meant to start fabrication in like 1970 before almost the entire apollo applications program aside from Skylab was thrown in the bin in 1967 because Congress didn't want to fund more than 15 Saturn Vs

@OT-64SKOT Yes, and in 1970, engineers thought they knew enough to begin fabrication of a base that could keep people alive on the Moon. They were wrong. We're still learning the practical engineering of keeping people alive in orbit, let alone on the Moon. If we had begun in 1970 using nuclear rockets we might, by 1990, have had some concept of actually being able to inaugurate a moon base "soon" - on the back of 20 years of failures and baby steps.

@Cadence: Yes, this is what the question/my answer is all about... what IF there would have been NERVA crafts in operation shortly after Apollo. I am best-guessing/speculating here. Ofc building a base would not have been without failures... but an unmanned base would be a first step already. A large portion of why we have no base on the moon today is, because we did not even try to setup one. We focused more on the LEO stuff (like ISS, Hubble) - which is fine. Needs to be done step by step.

@Cadence how the hell did they land people on the moon if they didn't know how to survive there? What would've made converting a LEM into a shelter/cargo vehicle that difficult?

@OT-64SKOT: Well, surviving a few hours on the surface and being stationed on the moon for weeks/months are two different things, I'd say.

@Antares the J missions (the last 3 apollo missions IRL, there was also meant to be a 4th that was canned to save a Saturn V for Skylab) lasted 3 days on the surface each and the first lunar habitats of the Apollo Applications Program were meant to last 2 weeks each before something like the LASS wet workshop would've been sent which was meant to last longer.
